# Google chart looses legend page index after call to chart.draw()

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Google line charts, are not working as expected, my system delivers data interactively and I need to update google chart interactively upon change. In order to do so, I call `chart.draw(...)` during every data upload. Unfortunately making such call resets visual state of the component.

Consider the following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1besonf5/85/

If you change the legend page it will get reset in a second. Due to

```
setInterval(() => chart.draw(data, chartOptions), 3000);
```

How do you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a solution to this. Paging legends are relatively new to the product, and I'm not aware of any part of the API to control this. Sounds like something to submit an issue for, in the [issues repository](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues).